# Node.js Solana websocket programSubscribe returning too many events

Tags: node.js, websocket, rpc, solana

I have a node.js file using Solana's JSON RPC websocket method programSubscribe. The problem I'm running into is that I'm getting events that happened up to a year ago. How do I use a filter to get only NEW events that happen after the socket is opened?

const socket = 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com';
socket.open();

```
try{
//function monitor() {
socket.onopen = () => {
  isWebSocketConnected(socket); 
  
  try{
    socket.send(
          JSON.stringify({
              jsonrpc: '2.0',
              id: 1,
              method: 'programSubscribe',
              params: [
                programID,
                  {
                      //encoding: 'base64',
                      encoding: 'jsonParsed',
                      commitment: 'finalized',
                  },
              ],
          })
      )
      isSubscribed = true;
      logToLogFile("Socket", "Subscription message sent"); 
    }catch(error){
      logToLogFile("SocketError", `Subscription message failed ${error}`); 
    }
}
```

}catch (error){
logToLogFile("SocketError", `Socket failed to open ${error}`);
}

I've tried to get the latest slot and compare to the current slot but year old data is coming in.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.